# What's the difference between disk backup and disk copy?

Tags: images

I'm confused and don't know which one to download:

http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/

Comment: Depending what are your needs but it looks like to be almost the same for both...

Answer (score 6):

"Todo Backup" copies all the files in a partition to a disc image. The size of the image will be the total size of all the files on the partition.

"Disk Copy" does an exact sector-by-sector [clone](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/disk-clone.htm) of the hard-drive. The size of the clone will be exactly the same as the total size of the hard-drive. The image may contain multiple partitions, and also files that were previously marked as deleted but physically still exist on the drive (i.e., files that were not securely erased).